# Javascript functionality for stop the browser page script, inside for loop , and continue later, that not overload browser?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sleep, babylonjs

Can't found the way to stop the script for loop, after each iteration , wait 0.5 sec , and continue, that browser not show me message dialog (block script, wait script).
for example:

```
var maxi = 10;
for( i=0;i<maxi;i++){
    //my babylonjs code which execute long, because no other way
    wait(0.5) // function which pause page script, relax cpu, and then again continue script next loop step
}
```

Attention please! I don't need run some code use setinterval etc... i just want relax CPU, and not more.
Stop the script, relax CPU, continue the script... every loop iteration.

Comment: Where is this `wait` function?

Comment: @zero298 the wait function is the root of question. I need this function or some ways to realize it.

Comment: If you need to "relax CPU" maybe the approach is wrong. If not you could try web workers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @Jonas Lochmann but in my case i can't use setInterval etc, because the time of calculating every loop iteration can be different, because parametric 3D model + mesh merge functionality. I just need to make relax after each iteration inside for loop.

Comment: Your only options are non-blocking functions that "suspend" the flow of the current context.  That means using `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, making an XHR request, or embracing event based IO.

Comment: If calculations are the blocking bottleneck, you need to switch to an event based pattern and offload your math to a worker as @Emeeus suggested.

Comment: @Emeeus if root for loop complete calculating before the workers return all results then will fail, because that calculate next step, need result mesh from previous subtraction step.

Comment: You could perform an ajax to nowhere that takes 100/200 ms and put the code in the callback, but it's almost the same as using setinterval.